# regex - how to match space and replace it with colon

Tags: regex, space

Text looks like this:

```
816 Organizational Relationships
832 Price/Sales Catalog
846 Inventory Inquiry/Advice
850 Purchase Order
855 Purchase Order Acknowledgment
```

I need to replace the first space with `,`

Thanks

Comment: This is a very basic regex question you could do on your own with 5 mins of googleing. Why dont you research a bit?

Comment: Which language? Javascript? Perl? Python? Ruby?

Comment: Your title says "how to match space and replace it with colon" but the punctuation you've shown, the `,`, is a comma.  A colon is `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace any first space-like character (such as tabs, or space) with a comma (replace `,` with `:` if you actually want a colon:

```
/\s/,/
```

(notice the lack of `g` flag)

Sample Bash run:

```
$> echo '816 Organizational Relationships
> 832 Price/Sales Catalog
> 846 Inventory Inquiry/Advice
> 850 Purchase Order
> 855 Purchase Order Acknowledgment' | sed -e 's/\s/,/'

816,Organizational Relationships
832,Price/Sales Catalog
846,Inventory Inquiry/Advice
850,Purchase Order
855,Purchase Order Acknowledgment
$>
```

Comment: hm, so it turns out the first gap was not a space but tab ;) And that's why none of the soultions I've found over the internet seamed to be working.

Comment: You said "space"... Updated my answer to match anything that looks "spacey".